# Image link moves on hover

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I am modifying the footer of a wordpress site to include four affiliate logos and their associated homepage URLs.
Whenever the image is hovered over, the image container shrinks and moves the page below it up slightly, as well as jolting the image slightly to the left.

URL: http://giant2.cogiva.com/

each image has the following CSS in addition to the theme default:

```
#image-9 a {
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
}

#image-9 a img {
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
}

#image-9 img {
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Remove your padding of your img, if you want space, apply padding (or margin) on a element and dont forget to apply display block or inline-block on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hover: `a img {padding: 4px }`

On hover: `a:hover img {padding: 0}`

In **style.css**, find and replace, row **681**:

```
a img       { border:1px solid #dedede; padding:4px; }
a:hover img { border:5px solid #2d3e4f; }
```